# Override update in Django Rest Framework without reimplementing the entire method?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So, I've been looking for a pattern or standard for this for a while, but I can't seem to find one.

Suppose I have some serializer:

```py
WhateverSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
      model = Whatever
      fields = (
           'special',
           'field_1',
           'field_2'
           #a bunch more...
      )
```

And I want to have some special update behaviour just for the field `special` but no other fields. Is there a way to to override `update` *without* having to redo the entire update method like this?

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    special_behaviour(instance.special)
    instance.field_1 = validated_data.get('field_1', instance.field_1)
    instance.field_2 = validated_data.get('field_2', instance.field_2)
    #a bunch more...
```

I've tried calling the `ModelViewSet.update` method, but it actually takes different parameters than the one you override in the viewset, and I'm not sure how exactly to pass the ones I have into that method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just remove the key from the dictionary of validated data, do your calculations, then use the super function to call the inherited update method which will `.save()` your changes.

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    special = validated.data.pop('special')
    instance.special = perform_calc(special)
    return super().update(instance, validated_data)
```

Comment: I tried calling out to the superclass, but I get `TypeError: update() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'`, and checking the actual definitions indicate that the `ModelViewSet.update` method doesn't take the same parameters for some reason.

Comment: Are you updating from your viewset or your serializer? It needs to be in the serializer. And that error means you have `pk=...` somewhere in your super. If you can update your question with your new code.

Comment: I was putting my code in the viewset, not the serializer. Oops.